# Hyperref and custom caption in float environment link wrong

Tags: floats, hyperref, captions

I have a custom caption style. If i add a reference to a float the link points to the caption which is below the floats content, but it should point to the top. I probably forgot to set a ref line or something like this.

The minimal Example is:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper, twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
% caption layout
\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{\textbf{#1} \\#2}} % with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ r }
      \hline
      TABLE HERE \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[caption heading]{\blindtext}
    \label{tab:table}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\blindtext
See Table \ref{tab:table}.
\end{document}
```

How could is set the link to the top of the float?

Comment: You redefined the `\caption` command's first argument to be heading, this will be added as the entry to the `List of tables` and could be too long? Concerning the link: Adding `\hypertarget{tab:table}{}` just after `\begin{table}[h]` should work.

Comment: But why doesn't it work like before anymore? if i use the default caption its pointing to the head automatically.
I redefined it to have the first argument in List of Tables and as a heading and the second as description text ...